# Microsoft Graph API webhook - getting multiple post to my notificationUrl

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I subscribed a Microsoft Graph API Webhook for every change in the groups on my tenant where usually I use it for testing and building PoC, I have only one subscription here.
I'm wondering if the behavior is normal considering that I changed the privacy of a group from private to public and now I get a change notification on my app(notification URL) every one minute.
nobody else is working on this group, is this behavior intended to work in this way?

[image]

What I expect in this case is to receive one notification for every change and not multiple notifications for the same change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Are you certain you created a single subscription? Any left over from testing?
2. Are you [replying to the notification with a 202-Accepted status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#processing-the-notification)? Perhaps it is retrying due to no response?

Comment: Thanks Paul my mistake not read in the documentation to return HTTP 202